# JAVAFX: Any way to get a stage that is already open?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, fxml

First, I'm sorry about my english and i am new here..
I'd like to know.. is there a way to get the stages that are already open on javafx ?

** **Something like "Application.OpenForms" from C#**

For example:

I have a menu with 3 items: Register, Reports and Help.
When I click on Register, it will open the register form for me. Then I click on Reports, it will open the reports for me. If I click on register again, the form that is already open will request the focus instead open a new form.

Someone help me, please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your main stage as a static variable. For example, you have the following main file.

```
public class Main extends Application {
public static Stage main_stage;
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    main_stage = stage;
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

So you can access your main_stage from anywhere by using Main.main_stage.

Comment: I would like to know, if is it possible to open a stage once.
Do you know ?